# How can i get document after yt-navigate-finish (chrome extension)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have huge problem with very funny thing. Actualy i have a code and when i want to `getAttribute`, always i got this same value (example: first `content="1234123123"`, after change video content should be changed but one more time i got `content="1234123123"`), but `window.location.href` returns normally.

It works normally if you refresh site, but it doesn't work after click on other video. Someone help me?

`Javascript`

```
window.addEventListener("yt-navigate-finish", function(event) {
  console.log("================== ")
  console.log($('body meta[itemprop=channelId]').attr("content"))
  console.log(window.location.href)

  let x = document.querySelector("#watch7-content meta[itemprop=channelId]")

  console.log(x.getAttribute("content"))

  let x2 = window.document.querySelector("#watch7-content meta[itemprop=channelId]")

  console.log(x2.getAttribute("content"))
});
```

`Manifest.json`

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*"],
      "js": [
        "lib/jquery-3.6.0.min.js",
        "initVideo.js"
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Replace `window.addEventListener` with `document.addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question was a bit on the confusing side :)

From what I understand you want to get the channel ID when you navigate to a new a video on YouTube.

If that's the case, the query that used here `document.querySelector("#watch7-content meta[itemprop=channelId]")` will not change every time you switch video.

This will:

```
document.addEventListener("yt-navigate-finish", function (event) {
    // The query is long, but it's not random, it make sense.
    const channelElement = document.querySelector("#primary-inner #meta .ytd-video-owner-renderer a");
    if (channelElement.href)
        console.log(channelElement.href.split("channel/")[1]);
});
```

Tell me if help or you meant something else :)

Comment: Thanks, but this code give me always previously channel id. i used setTimeout for querySelector with 1000ms and everything working, you are the boss

Comment: Cool! How did you found the name of the event "yt-navigate-finish"? I want to know about more youtube native events :)

Comment: Here you can find https://scrapbox.io/mabasasi/youtube_event_%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A8%E3%82%81